# Force Window to be reactive, but never gain Focus

Tags: c#, wpf, window, focus

The main window of my application should not be allowed to gain focus at any time as it is called by another application that continuously needs focus when working with it. Also, my application is always TopMost, only allowed to run wwith one instance and
when called will handle the command line args to run in a different context. This part is already handled and runs well.

I´m not able to achieve not getting focus for some reason. I´ve tried for several hours using different solutions - all don´t work as I expect them to. First of all, here´s the relevant XAML of the main window:

```
<mah:MetroWindow x:Class="Sprachrekorder.Code.View.Gui"
    x:Name="G"
    ...
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    ResizeMode="NoResize"
    WindowStartupLocation="Manual" 
    ShowTitleBar="true" 
    Topmost="True"
    ShowActivated="False" <- ONLY WORKS WHEN INITIALLY RUNNING THE PROGRAM, BUT FAILS WHEN CALLING THE SAME (ALREADY RUNNING) INSTANCE AGAIN
    Focusable="False"     <- HAS NO IMPACT
    SourceInitialized="Gui_OnSourceInitialized"
    d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance {x:Type viewModel:MainViewModel}, IsDesignTimeCreatable=False}"
    ShowCloseButton="False"
    cust:WindowPosition.IsLocked="{Binding Settings.ActualConfig.WindowFixed, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
```

Main Window Code behind:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
private static extern int GetWindowLong(IntPtr hwnd, int index);

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
private static extern int SetWindowLong(IntPtr hwnd, int index, int newStyle);

//private static IntPtr GetWindowLongPtr ( IntPtr hWnd, int index ) <- USING THIS CODE ALSO HAS NO IMPACT
//{
//    return (IntPtr.Size == 4) ? GetWindowLongPtrA(hWnd, index) : GetWindowLongPtrW(hWnd, index);
//}

//private static IntPtr SetWindowLongPtr ( IntPtr hWnd, int index, IntPtr newValue )
//{
//    return (IntPtr.Size == 4) ? SetWindowLongPtrA(hWnd, index, newValue) : SetWindowLongPtrW(hWnd, index, newValue);
//}

//[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "GetWindowLongPtr", SetLastError = true)]
//private static extern IntPtr GetWindowLongPtrW ( IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex );

//[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "GetWindowLong", SetLastError = true)]
//private static extern IntPtr GetWindowLongPtrA ( IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex );

//[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetWindowLongPtr", SetLastError = true)]
//private static extern IntPtr SetWindowLongPtrW ( IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, IntPtr dwNewLong );

//[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetWindowLong", SetLastError = true)]
//private static extern IntPtr SetWindowLongPtrA ( IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, IntPtr dwNewLong );

public Gui()
{
    Main = new MainViewModel();
    DataContext = Main;
    InitializeComponent();
    Main.Init();
    Loaded += (s, e) =>
    {
        WindowHandle = new WindowInteropHelper(Application.Current.MainWindow ?? throw new InvalidOperationException()).Handle;
        HwndSource.FromHwnd(WindowHandle)?.AddHook(HandleMessages);

        //Set the window style to noactivate.  <- DOES NOT WORK
        var currentValue = GetWindowLongPtr(WindowHandle, GWL_EXSTYLE);
        var newValue = new IntPtr(currentValue.ToInt64() | WS_EX_NOACTIVATE);
        SetWindowLongPtr(WindowHandle, GWL_EXSTYLE, newValue);
    };
}

private static IntPtr HandleMessages(IntPtr handle, int message, IntPtr wParameter, IntPtr lParameter, ref Boolean handled)
{
    //Deactivate Window focus completely <- ONLY SEEMS TO WORK IN DEBUG
    if (message == WM_MOUSEACTIVATE)
    {
        handled = true;
        return new IntPtr(MA_NOACTIVATE);
    }

    if (handle != WindowHandle) return IntPtr.Zero;

    var data = UnsafeNative.GetMessage(message, lParameter); <- THIS PART HANDLES THE COMMAND LINE ARGS IF APPLICATION IS ALREADY RUNNING AND IS CALLED AGAIN
    if (data == null || Application.Current.MainWindow == null) return IntPtr.Zero;
    if (Application.Current.MainWindow.WindowState == WindowState.Minimized) Application.Current.MainWindow.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;

    UnsafeNative.SetForegroundWindow(new WindowInteropHelper(Application.Current.MainWindow).Handle);

    var args = data.Split(' ');
    HandleParameter(args);
    handled = true;
    return IntPtr.Zero;
}

private void Gui_OnSourceInitialized(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var interopHelper = new WindowInteropHelper(this); // <- THIS CODE PART HAS NO IMPACT
    int exStyle = GetWindowLong(interopHelper.Handle, GWL_EXSTYLE);
    SetWindowLong(interopHelper.Handle, GWL_EXSTYLE, exStyle | WS_EX_NOACTIVATE);
}
```

Parts of the UnsafeNative class:

```
public const int WM_COPYDATA = 0x004A;

public static string GetMessage(int message, IntPtr lParam)
{
    if (message != WM_COPYDATA) return null;
    try
    {
        var data = Marshal.PtrToStructure<COPYDATASTRUCT>(lParam);
        var result = string.Copy(data.lpData);
        return result;
    }
    catch
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I have commented the relevant parts in my code. The most effective part seems to be

```
if (message == WM_MOUSEACTIVATE)
{
    handled = true;
    return new IntPtr(MA_NOACTIVATE);
}
```

in the HandleMessages-Method of the main class, but this only works in Debug. Also when clicking on the app in the windows taskbar it regains focus. What can I do to remove the focus of the window? Does anybody have an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone who´s interested - this is how I solved my problem: All above did not get me to the point I wanted to be, so I thought, maybe I can just give the focus back to the window loosing the focus. That worked out and I added the following code to the code behind class of the main window:

```
public partial class Gui
{
    //...

    //Added code below**************************
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern IntPtr GetWindow(IntPtr hWnd, uint uCmd);
    enum GetWindow_Cmd : uint
    {
        GW_HWNDFIRST = 0,
        GW_HWNDLAST = 1,
        GW_HWNDNEXT = 2,
        GW_HWNDPREV = 3,
        GW_OWNER = 4,
        GW_CHILD = 5,
        GW_ENABLEDPOPUP = 6
    }
    [DllImport("user32.dll", ExactSpelling = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern IntPtr GetParent(IntPtr hWnd);
    //******************************************

    private static IntPtr HandleMessages(IntPtr handle, int message, IntPtr wParameter, IntPtr lParameter, ref Boolean handled)
    {
        if (handle != WindowHandle) return IntPtr.Zero;

        var data = UnsafeNative.GetMessage(message, lParameter);
        if (data == null || Application.Current.MainWindow == null) return IntPtr.Zero;
        if (Application.Current.MainWindow.WindowState == WindowState.Minimized) Application.Current.MainWindow.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;

        UnsafeNative.SetForegroundWindow(new WindowInteropHelper(Application.Current.MainWindow).Handle);

        var args = data.Split(' ');
        HandleParameter(args);
        handled = true;

        //Added code below********************************
        //Set focus to the window that previously had the focus
        IntPtr lastWindowHandle = GetWindow(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle, (uint)GetWindow_Cmd.GW_HWNDNEXT);
        while (true)
        {
            IntPtr temp = GetParent(lastWindowHandle);
            if (temp.Equals(IntPtr.Zero)) break;
            lastWindowHandle = temp;
        }
        UnsafeNative.SetForegroundWindow(lastWindowHandle);
        //************************************************
        return IntPtr.Zero;
    }

    //***
}
```

The rest of the code for that class is in my original post. Code is from https://www.whitebyte.info/programming/how-to-get-main-window-handle-of-the-last-active-window